# Posting a form to an iframe. Blocked frame with origin error on Chrome windows 8

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have a form which is posting a file upload to an iFrame:

```
<form id="upload-form" method="post" action="http://xxxxxxx.com/artist/tracks/upload_complete" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload-frame">
...............
    <input name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit">
</form>
<iframe id="upload-frame" name="upload-frame"></iframe>
```

It is working fine on every browser in windows 7, and osx, however the client has informed me that it's not working for him on chrome on windows 8. I remote desktopped in to look at the error console and it reads

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://xxxxxxx.com"
>   from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting
>   access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a
>   protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

Looks like an issue with the same origin policy however both the form and the iframe reside on the same domain.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Is anything parentframe or child frame on localhost ?

Comment: @bludnerboy not sure if I follow your question. Either way, the project is not on localhost. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, you have **an iframe with no src defined** that is why you are getting null origin error.

```
<iframe id="upload-frame" name="upload-frame"></iframe>
```

Try to set value of src as

- `javascript:false` (Works in all browsers except IE10)
- `#` (I guess works in all browsers)

Example Usage:

```
<iframe id="upload-frame" name="upload-frame" src="javascript:false"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've put the fix in place and waiting to hear back from the client.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've set the original source of the iFrame to the homepage of the site incase the hash or javascript:false were causing an issue. I'll let you know how it goes. Cheers

Comment: @Fraser Thanks a lot. I would love to know the solution for this problem.

Comment: any news abuot the solution?